# Read rows from a Excel worksheet in Logic App

Tags: excel, parsing, azure-logic-apps

I'm struggling with getting the rows present in an Excel worksheet in my Logic App. Even Google did not give me reasonable answers unfortunately.

I can get the Worksheet(s) with the "Get Worksheets" Action but I have problems with reading the rows from it. Currently I am using the "Excel Online (Business)" connector.

The excel will only contain one single Worksheet and no Table. Otherwise I could have used the "List Rows in a Table" Action but this scenario is actually not possible.

Could one give me some advice on how to read the rows from an Excel-Worksheet?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We must have a table established in our Excel file before using the `Excel Online (Business)` connections.

In order to add a table select all the concerned cells and navigate to Insert > Click Table. Now add the Table Name in `List rows present in Table` or `Get a row` connectors to retrieve the data.

- Here are the screenshots for reference:

  [image]
- The outputs of two connectors:[image]

  [image]
- Here are the sample Excel files that are used :

  **sampleee.xlsx**

  [image]

  **duplicates.xlsx**

  [image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As mentioned in my post the excel is created by an automated process, so a Table cannot be added before Logic App processing.

I have solved the problem by adding a table from within the Logic App by selecting an appropriate range of cells and columns. After that I select the rows by adding a filter, to get only the rows containing data.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is not possible to add a Table-Area in the excel prior the Logic App processing because of the way the Excel file is delivered I have solved the problem by explicitly adding a Table in the Logic App to the incoming Excel file and filter it in "Get Rows present in table" to get only the rows containing data.

[image]